# Я не могу понять, что мешает переносу строк

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть сценарий при использовании библиотеки typed.js . Я пытаюсь вывести 3 строки + 1 последнюю. Код работает, выводя 2 строки + 1 последнюю. При попытке исправить это код зависает без отправки сообщения об ошибке.

Эта версия кода работает без ошибок. Выводит 2 линии + 1.
[image: out]

```js
  const lineNumber = app.id !== 2 ? ++app.id : (app.id += 2);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const typed = new Typed(`#line${lineNumber}`, {
      strings: text,
      typeSpeed: speed,
      onComplete: callback,
    });
  }, timeout);
};

$.getJSON(ipgeolocation, (data) => {
  writeLine(["line1"], 30, () => {
    if (app.skippedIntro) return;

    clearCursor();

    const usernames = ['user', 'dude'];

    const ip = data.ip ? data.ip : usernames[Math.floor(Math.random() * usernames.length)];
    const country = data.country_name ? data.country_name : 'your country';

    writeLine([`line2`], 30, 500, () => {
      if (app.skippedIntro) return;
      
      clearCursor();
        
      writeLine([`start`], 120, 500, () => {
        timeouts.push(
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (app.skippedIntro) return;

            clearCursor();

            setTimeout(() => {
              skipIntro();
            }, 500);
          }, 1000)
        );
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Эта версия кода не работает. Согласно идее, он должен выводить 3 строки + 1.[image: out]

```js
  const lineNumber = app.id !== 2 ? ++app.id : (app.id += 2);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const typed = new Typed(`#line${lineNumber}`, {
      strings: text,
      typeSpeed: speed,
      onComplete: callback,
    });
  }, timeout);
};

$.getJSON(ipgeolocation, (data) => {
  writeLine(["line1"], 30, () => {
    if (app.skippedIntro) return;

    clearCursor();

    const usernames = ['user', 'dude'];

    const ip = data.ip ? data.ip : usernames[Math.floor(Math.random() * usernames.length)];
    const country = data.country_name ? data.country_name : 'your country';

    writeLine([`line2`], 30, 500, () => {
      if (app.skippedIntro) return;
      
      clearCursor();

      writeLine([`line3`], 30, 500, () => {
        if (app.skippedIntro) return;
        
        clearCursor();
        
        writeLine([`start`], 120, 500, () => {
        timeouts.push(
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (app.skippedIntro) return;

            clearCursor();

            setTimeout(() => {
              skipIntro();
            }, 500);
          }, 1000)
        );
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как нужно перенести с 3 строки на 5, нужно было исправить значения app.id.

Решение:

```js
 const lineNumber = app.id !== 3 ? ++app.id : (app.id += 2);
```